# Por que não cria Foreign Key?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql, chave-estrangeira, chave-primária

Executei os comandos no MySql Workbench, porém não criou a ligação da Foreign Key, o que está errado nas querys?

```
create table Computador (
    ID int NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nome varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    Marca varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    Modelo varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    Processador varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    MemoriaRam smallint NOT NULL,
    TamanhoTotal int NOT NULL
);

create table MaquinaVirtual (
    ID int NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nome varchar(70) NOT NULL,
    EspacoEmUso int NOT NULL, 
    EspacoTotal int NOT NULL,
    IdComputador int NOT NULL,
    foreign key (IdComputador) references Computador (ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa setar a engine das tabelas para InnoDB:

```sql
create table Computador (
    ID int NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nome varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    Marca varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    Modelo varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    Processador varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    MemoriaRam smallint NOT NULL,
    TamanhoTotal int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

create table MaquinaVirtual (
    ID int NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nome varchar(70) NOT NULL,
    EspacoEmUso int NOT NULL, 
    EspacoTotal int NOT NULL,
    IdComputador int NOT NULL,
    foreign key (IdComputador) references Computador (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Referências:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/foreign-keys/

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO!